# Compare two XML trees in Java

Tags: java, xml, tree

I have 2 XML and I need compare if there trees have the same tags but in diferents positions something like that:

```
             A                                 A
            / \                               / \ 
           B   C                             C   B
          / \                                   / \
         1   2                                 2   3
```

The tree B have 1 node in common in 2 cases .
Something more complex like notepad++ compare plugin do. I need to compare node by node, positions and values. Do you know about if some library can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use any XML API to convert your XML into objects and then compare their values.

Comment: Thanks! I find the code of notepad++ compare plugin and they make something like this but a lot more complex...

Answer (score 0):

Use an xml parser to marshall your xml to a java object, lets call it MyXMLData. Override the equals method in your MyXMLData Java class and you can compare the two objects.

Comment: thanks! But I want something more complex like notepad++ compare plugin do. I need to compare node by node, positions and values. Do you know about if some library can do it?